# Application of Complex Variables

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, contour-integration

Considering the integral :

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\left(\dfrac{\sin\alpha z}{\alpha z}\right)^2 \dfrac{\pi}{\sin{\pi} z}dz,\quad \alpha \lt \dfrac{\pi}{2}$$

around a circle of large radius, prove that

$$\sum\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{m-1}\dfrac{\sin^2m\alpha}{(m\alpha)^2}=\dfrac{1}{2}$$

If anyone can help me in going about doing this?

Comment: Bound the integrand on the contour by something that decays as the circle's radius tends to infinity, then use the Residue Theorem on the poles in the interior. That's harsh, though, asking for it to be done with a circle: a square is much easier to use.

Comment: @Chappers I was thinking a square would be much easier. now im stuck :p

Comment: Okay, try this: you can bound a circle by squares inside and outside. Is that any easier? (maybe not...)

Answer (score 1):

The function written above has poles of the first order at points $z=n$, where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. All because of the $\sin{\pi z}$ in the denominator : The function itself has a linear behaviour in the neighbourhood of all its zeros, so they are of the first order. The $\alpha$ part does not count in pole-behaviour, albeit it looks loke it has a singularity, it has not. (Because the apparent singularity is removable)

Now, consider a contour infinitely large (or just limitingly huge), it containts all poles exept the one at infinity. As you probably know, you can compute the integral on that contour by using the Residue formula, the information is extracted from poles which this contour encloses - i.e. the integral is sum of the residues times a constant. Now, if you know a little bit from projection, you can imagine that the whole complex plain is just so the Riemann sphere. With little bit of imagination you can see now that there are two ways of defining region which that contour encloses, so the poles IN the region could be :

$(1)$ All the integer value poles on the real line (positively oriented contour)

or

$(2)$ Just point on the top of the sphere (infinite point) (negatively or.c.)

Let us compute the residue at each integer point $z=n$, unsing the definition of the residue, the by the L'Hopital's rule :

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=n}{f(z)}:=\lim_{z \to n} f(z)(z-n) = \lim_{z \to n} \left(\frac{\sin{\alpha z}}{\alpha z}\right)^2 \pi \frac{z-n}{\sin{\pi z}} = \lim_{z \to n} \left(\frac{\sin{\alpha z}}{\alpha z}\right)^2\frac{1}{\cos{\pi z}} = \left(\frac{\sin{\alpha n}}{\alpha n}\right)^2 (-1)^n $$

Of course, at $n=0$, using this limit is equal to $1$

Nevertheless, the residuum at infinity simply vanishes, so, by the fact the value of the contour integral is independent on the "wiew in/out", so does the sum of the residue at integer valued points, therefore :

$$\therefore \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin{\alpha n}}{\alpha n}\right)^2 (-1)^n=0$$

Now, we can separate the sum into two sympetric sums starting at 1 (excluding n=0)

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\left(\frac{\sin{\alpha n}}{\alpha n}\right)^2 (-1)^n = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=-1}\left(\frac{\sin{\alpha n}}{\alpha n}\right)^2 (-1)^n 
 + 1 + \sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\left(\frac{\sin{\alpha n}}{\alpha n}\right)^2 (-1)^n$$

By symmetry (just even function) the two mani sums are equal (because every term is equal), regrupping gives the result which have to be showed.

(Albeit I thing there may be far more rigorous aproaches, from the physicist point of view this may be sufficient)

Comment: Okay, but what you have not shown is that the value of the integrand on the contour decays to zero as you take it larger and larger. For any finite value of the radius, you still have infinitely many poles (and so residues) outside. There's also the problem that (therefore) you have an essential singularity at $\infty$, which doesn't let you use the argument available for polynomials about looking at the inside and outside of the contour.